# Why my spring-label-label-spring auto layout constraints don't work?

Tags: ios, spring, swift2, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to horizontally center labels within its container, using UIView acting as springs on the two sides.

Unfortunately, the system tells it can satisfy all constraints, hence the wrong result. But I can come up with a solution.

My code is as follows:

```
 func addSpringConstraints(items: [UIView], mainView: UIView, spacing: CGFloat) {

    let pad = spacing / 2

    var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()


    // Add two spacer to serve as springs
    let lSpring = UIView()
    lSpring.frame.size.width = 50
    //lSpring.hidden = true
    lSpring.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    lSpring.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(lSpring)

    let rSpring = UIView()
    rSpring.frame.size.width = lSpring.frame.size.width
    //rSpring.hidden = true
    rSpring.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
    rSpring.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(rSpring)


    // Constraint left spring
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lSpring, attribute: .Top,    relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top,    multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lSpring, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lSpring, attribute: .Left,   relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Left,   multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


    // Constraint right spring
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: rSpring, attribute: .Top,    relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top,    multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: rSpring, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: rSpring, attribute: .Right,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Right,  multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


    for (index, segment) in items.enumerate() {

        // Add top and bottom constraints

        constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Top,    relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Top,    multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: mainView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))


        // Add left constraint if any and width constraint

        if index == 0 {
            let prev = lSpring          // first label is attached to the left spring
            constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: prev, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
        else {
            let prev = items[index-1]   // label attached to the previous label by its left side
            constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: prev, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1, constant: pad))

            // Same width than first segment
            constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: items.first, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }


        // Add right constraints if any

        if index == items.count - 1 {
            let next = rSpring          // last label is attached to the right spring
            constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: next, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        }
        else {
            let next = items[index+1]   // label attached to the next label by its right side
            constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: segment, attribute: .Right, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: next, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1, constant: -pad))
        }
    }

    // Add all constraints to the view
    mainView.addConstraints(constraints)
}
```

Here is the issues for spring -"PHOTO" - "LIVE VIDEO" - spring :

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x14ddf0d60 h=--& v=--& H:[Visage.ZEENSUISegmentedControl:0x14df01300(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dec1490 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x14debe390](LTR)   (Names: '|':Visage.ZEENSUISegmentedControl:0x14df01300 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14deaabb0 UIView:0x14deaaa40.right == Visage.ZEENSUISegmentedControl:0x14df01300.right>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14deb7780 H:[UIView:0x14debe390]-(0)-[UILabel:0x14df3af70'PHOTO'](LTR)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14deaada0 UILabel:0x14df3af70'PHOTO'.right == UILabel:0x14debe9e0'LIVE VIDEO'.left - 22.5>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dea5930 UILabel:0x14debe9e0'LIVE VIDEO'.width == UILabel:0x14df3af70'PHOTO'.width>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14dea5980 UILabel:0x14debe9e0'LIVE VIDEO'.right == UIView:0x14deaaa40.left>"
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the issue, by experimenting further.

The thing is that the spacers must have the same size (actually the width) in order for the "spring" behavior, so I added the additional constraint as follows:

```
    // Constraint right spring
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: lSpring, attribute: .Width,  relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: rSpring,  attribute: .Width,  multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

It turns out that this additional constraint has to be set in order to limit to only one degree of liberty (the evenly space on the left and the right). If we don't add this constraint, the underlying code in charge of solving the constraint has multiple solutions: left=0 or right=0 among others.